# Javascript: remove trailing spaces only

Tags: javascript

Can anyone help me on how to remove trailing spaces in JavaScript. 
I want to keep the leading spaces as is and only remove trailing spaces.
EG: `'    test    '` becomes `'    test'`.
Seems like pretty simple but I can't figure it out.

PS: I am pretty sure I can't be the first one to ask this but I can't find an answer in SO. Also, I am looking for JavaScript solution. I am not using jQuery.

Comment: Just install [trim](https://www.npmjs.com/package/trim) via npm. It was installed nearly 10,000 times yesterday. After all, [what could go wrong](http://www.haneycodes.net/npm-left-pad-have-we-forgotten-how-to-program/)? Haha, I must laugh so I don't cry.

Comment: @MichaelPlotke Why do you think he's using node.js?

Comment: There are lots of questions about removing both leading and trailing whitespace, but I can't find a duplicate that's just about removing trailing spaces.

Comment: why the downvotes?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Use **[`String#replace`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace)** with regex **[`/\s+$/`](https://regex101.com/r/nK3rC3/1)** and replacing text as empty string.

```
string.replace(/\s+$/, '')
```

```js
console.log(
  '-----' + '    test    '.replace(/\s+$/, '') + '-----'
)
```

Comment: @frankies `\s` matches all types of whitespace.

Comment: @Barmar Yep. If people want to just replace spaces (not linebreaks and such), they should use `string.replace(/ +$/, '')`.

Comment: Do the forward slashes at the beginning and end of the first argument indicate that the first argument is a regular expression?

Answer (score 3):

#### Update 2019

String trim methods have been added to [ECMAScript spec](https://tc39.es/ecma262/multipage/text-processing.html#sec-string.prototype.trimend) in [2019](https://github.com/tc39/proposals/blob/main/finished-proposals.md) with wide [browser support](https://caniuse.com/mdn-javascript_builtins_string_trimend)

- [**`String.trim()`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/Trim)
- [**`String.trimStart()`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/trimStart)
- [**`String.trimEnd()`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/trimEnd)

You can use like this:

```js
" test ".trimEnd() // " test"
```

#### Further Reading

- [**tc39 proposal** - `String.prototype.{trimStart,trimEnd}`](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-string-left-right-trim)

Answer (score 2):

```
"    test    ".replace(/\s+$/g, '');
```

Comment: No point in having the `g` flag with this regex as `\s+` already covers all the trailing spaces

Answer (score 2):

Regex is worth knowing. But in case you don't, and don't want to use code you're not comfortable with, nor dive down that rabbit-hole for your current issue, here's a simple manual workaround:

```js
/**
 * @example
 * trimEndSpaces('test   \n   '); // Returns: 'test   \n'
 * @param {string} str 
 * @returns {string}
 */
function trimEndSpaces(str) {
  let i = str.length - 1;
  // decrement index while character is a space
  while (str[i] === ' ') {
    i--;
  }
  // return string from 0 to non-space character
  return str.slice(0, i + 1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use trimRight()

```
var x ="   test   "

x.trimRight()
```

Comment: And browser support of that non-standard method is bad.

Comment: Thank you epascarello

I was not aware of that i just verified on chrome and firefox 38
Its not working in I.E 11

Answer (score 0):

There is a way by which you can create a regex inside the replace method like  str.replace(/\s+$/g,'') will remove all trailing spaces.

Comment: You don't need the `g` modifier, since something that's anchored can't have multiple matches.

Comment: Yup you are right , my bad because this pattern will be unique so no need of g[global]

Comment: Did you read the red warning at the beginning of the page you linked to?

Comment: Yes... that is why i just gave the reference not posted the method.

Comment: I think posting the link seems like a recommendation to use it.