# Check if there is white space between letters in a string - IGNORE SPACE, TAB AND ENTER AT THE END OF THE WORD

Tags: javascript

I have searched and found ways to check for ALL whitespace existence between letters in a string but what about if the string contains a space, tab or enter at the end?

For example:

```
let str="John ";
console.log(str.includes(' '));
```

The above `console.log` will return true because there is a space at the end, however that is not relevant for me. I only wanted to check for:

```
let str="J o h n";
```

How to achieve this with Javascript ( and totally **ignore space check at the end**)?

Comment: `let str=" J o h n      ".trim()`

Comment: I think OP does not want to trim(), just remove in between whitespaces

Comment: yes that is right, I want to check if there are spaces between letters but ignore the space at the end.

Comment: @mplungjan I dont think its a duplicate of the question you tagged

Comment: it's not a duplicate, unless I searched wrongly, I could not find any answers that could help me.

Comment: Then it is a dupe of [remove-trailing-spaces-only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37864460/javascript-remove-trailing-spaces-only)

Comment: `console.log(str.trim().includes(' '));` will do exactly what you want

Comment: It is a condensed version of my [first comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71426218/check-if-there-is-white-space-between-letters-in-a-string-ignore-space-tab-an?noredirect=1#comment126248459_71426218); `let str=" J o h n      ".trim(); console.log(str.includes(' '));`

Comment: function splitCheck(str){
for(let o of str.trim().split(' ')){
 if( !o)
     return false
};
    return true;
}
tou can try this

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, this is what you want to achieve:

```
let str="John ";
console.log(/\s$/.test(str));
```

Comment: this returns true however it should return false because I don't care about space at the end